# Malloc string and edit it

Tags: c, string, malloc

i create here some space of malloc and with that a 2 dynamic array.

it have colorbuffer[0 to 256][0 to 4].
and i read a bmp file out and put the colors into.

now i want to change the color settings but this isnt working

like colorbuffer[0][0] = "255"

now the first color the red value should be 255

**but then my programm shuts down.**
also like colorbuffer[233][2] = "23"
the color 233 the value of green should be now 23.

and i also cant print it out like
printf("Color senitive %d", colorbuffer[0][1]);

**SOME PASSAGES OUT OF THE SOURCE** -> http://pastebin.com/fRD5w1XC

Hope you can help me would be awesome thank you

**edit // Done the fail was the & on read and write to &colorbuffer !
thank you stackoverflow !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
fread(&colorbuffer[i] //With &
```

into

```
fread(colorbuffer[i] //No &
```

The current program is overwriting your colorbuffer table, and causing all kinds of trouble afterwards because of it.

Comment: Turns out you had more than one bug!. Check Ansi's answer for why you are getting a segfault after changing the `&`

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate to up to 256 instead of 4 here:

```
  for (i=0;i<256;i++) //original code *for (i=0;i<4;i++)*
  {
  colorbuffer[i]=malloc(4*sizeof(unsigned char)); // colorbuffer[256][4]
  }
```

Compiler should give you a warning If you would like to compile something like:

```
colorbuffer[0][0] = "255"
```

because colorbuffer[0][0] is **char** not a **pointer to char**.

```
  for(i=0; i < ( (int)Datenheader.colors - 1 ); i++)
  {
  fread(&colorbuffer[i], sizeof(unsigned char),4,fp);
  wo = ftell(fp);
  }
```

I will guess that you do not need to subtract -1 here from total color count (e.g. if you will have 256 colors you will read from file only 255 colors. It means that 256th color, which is in array colorbuffer[255] wont be initialized at all)

And of course another bug that ***missingno*** reported to you about **&** usage in fread.

Comment: "colorbuffer[0][0] is char not a pointer to char." how then i put the then into the 30 color the red value to 200? so i mean the colorbuffer[30][0] = 200 ? ...

Comment: awesome i found the bug ... it was the & what @missingno mean !!! i use it in read and write the &. now i removed it and it works !!

Comment: @Mysterigs: Cool, but you actually had 4 bugs in the code you posted to us.

Answer (score 0):

My C days are long gone but...

```
void* buffer = malloc( sizeof(uchar) * numOfColors * 4 );

uchar** colors = (uchar**)buffer;

colors[0][1] = 1;

free( buffer );
```